# Auto slideshow gets messed up after clicking on the different slides few times

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, slideshow

Okay, so let me apologize in case i fail to describe my problem properly here....i am just not sure how to explain the problem!

On our page we have this one section with an auto slideshow where we have 4 tabs (heading on top and a small description) on the LHS and their contents on the RHS.
[image]

The slideshow works perfectly for first few minutes....but after some times (or if i click on the LHS tabs few times) the position of the tabs get messed up (in every browser). Just like the image below, the selected/active tab's description gets either cut off or disappears totally and the space between the tabs also gets messed up.
[image]

Can anyone please help me understand what's going on here and how can i fix this?

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/walahh/LrFWC/3/

Comment: Your jsfiddle looks nothing like the screen shot. Please make sure your images and background images have absolute links to them.

Comment: Your new [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/walahh/LrFWC/3/) looks closer but is still not working. Without a working example it is very difficult to troubleshoot.

Comment: sorry, i am trying, but the server is giving me hard time here. may be i'll post the link to the page in few minutes. thanks for your patience!

Comment: You are using a very old version of jQuery. See what happens if you use v1.7.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be using a very old version of jQuery. Often problems like this can be solved by using the latest version (1.7.2) instead.